# How to do good async?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I'm a PHP developer and currently i'm working on a node.js project, i've never experienced async before so it confusing me.

Am I really have to do it like this?

```
// user model
exports.getRandomUser = function(cb){
    db.query('...query...', cb);
}
// post model
exports.getRandomPost = function(uid, cb){
    db.query('...query...', cb);
}
// router
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    user.getRandomUser(function(userInfo){
        post.getRandomPost(userInfo.id, function(postInfo){
            res.render('post', {data: postInfo});
        });
    });
});
```

Is there any way to make it less confusing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question, yes there is a more simplified manner. What you are doing here is callback after callback, which makes the code look 'confusing'

Commonly referred to as **callback hell**

It looks pretty now for standards, but in time it will grow into a hungry programming power beast that needs your attention all the time.

For a javascript pro it's not really hard to deal with it, but if you want to have a more relaxed style at approaching callbacks; you can use *promises*. Promises are a way into the future for JS, but I think it's good to understand **BOTH**

a callback mostly has two parameters it looks like this:

```
dothis(function (error, data) {
     if (error) {
          throw new Error(error)
     }

     console.log('we have data', data)
})
```

With promises, this becomes much more easy to understand in the semantic terms

```
 dothis.then(function(data) {
     console.log('we have data', data)
 }).catch(function(error) { 
     throw new Error(error)
 })
```

This of course only works if your functions are promise compatible, if you want to learn more about promises check out this tutorial github:  https://github.com/then/promise

You can even chain promises and create a really clean codebase!